# How can I find the SID for an app pool via Microsoft.Web.Administration?

Tags: c#, iis, localization

I am working on a configuration tool that needs to set some permissions on a directory based on the identity that a specific web application runs under.  The original code simply built the login name based on `IIS APPPOOL\<ApppoolName>` or based on the well know SID if it was a built in account.

Some similar code failed in a localized environment so I am now trying to get rid of the baked in string.

My solution was this:

```
public static SecurityIdentifier GetApplicationPoolSid(string name)
    {
        ApplicationPool pool = Manager.ApplicationPools[name];
        if (pool != null)
        {
            var sddlForm = pool.GetAttributeValue("applicationPoolSid") as string;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sddlForm))
                return new SecurityIdentifier(sddlForm);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The problem is that I found `"applicationPoolSid"` by poking around in the debugger and I cannot find any documentation that says that I am not taking advantage of an undocumented implementation feature that will go away in the future.  (This means it won't pass code review.)

I would love to know the approved way of doing what I am looking at here.  I would also be happy to know that `IIS APPPOOL\<ApppoolName>` is guaranteed to never be localized so then we could go back to the old way.

Comment: What is it you're trying to actually accomplish by getting the SID?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch the SID is passed to the constructor for FileSystemAccessRule to provide access to shared logging directory.

Answer (score 1):

I can find no reference to `IIS APPPOOL` being localized, which would make sense since neither IIS nor APPPOOL are words in any language, so there's nothing to translate to. Although they are acronyms in English and possibly other languages, I think they are still called IIS and AppPool even in other languages.

You can, by the way, get the `SID` officially like this:

```
NTAccount f = new NTAccount(@"IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool");
SecurityIdentifier s = (SecurityIdentifier)f.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
String sidString = s.ToString();
```

You don't even really need the `SID` if you're going to pass it to `FileSystemAccessRule()`, since it has an overload that takes an `IdentityReference`, which `NTAccount` is.  Just pass it the `NTAccount`.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the SID, but does not use the function you asked about and is written in powershell not C#. I am posting this to hopefully assist in getting on the right track regarding the generation using SHA1 rather than actually querying from Windows. Also some systems do not have some SID and user account modules installed so this can be used in those situations.

Function to generate SID based off apppool username (explanation in link at the bottom)

```
function Get-SID ([String]$winver, [String]$username) {

    $sidPrefix = switch ($winver) {
        '6.0' { 'S-1-5-80' }
        default { 'S-1-5-82' }
    }

    $userToString = switch ( $sidPrefix ) {
        'S-1-5-82' { $username.ToLower() }
        default { $username.ToUpper() }
    }

    $userBytes = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($userToString)
    $sha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
    $hash = $sha.ComputeHash($userBytes)

    $sid = $sidPrefix

    for ( $i=0; $i -lt 5; $i++ ) {
        $sid += '-' + [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($hash, $i*4)
    }

    return $sid
}
```

Example usage

```
Get-SID -winver "6.0" -username "DefaultAppPool"
```

User 6.0 for Vista or equivalent release, use 6.1/6.2 etc for after that.

Partial credit to Tomas Restrepo from [winterdom.com](https://winterdom.com/2014/05/16/iis-apppool-identity-sids) for the powershell, although that script does not actually work because some functions are not included in the code.